# Count employees per hour

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in mssql that goes like this:

```
Operator    Time                    Event
DG01E0020   2018-01-27 09:36:46.000 12
DG01E0020   2018-01-27 15:25:53.000 13 
DG01E0027   2018-01-27 10:54:53.000 12
DG01E0027   2018-01-27 19:39:13.000 13
DG01E0025   2018-01-27 11:48:44.000 12
DG01E0025   2018-01-27 15:32:02.000 13
DG01E0013   2018-01-27 12:02:56.000 12
DG01E0013   2018-01-27 17:50:41.000 13
```

I want the number of employees per hour:

```
Time.    Count
8:00     0
9:00     1
10:00    2
11:00    3
12:00    8

Etc..
```

If it can help I have this query:

```
declare @ontem datetime
declare @hoje datetime
set @ontem = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE() - 1, 101) + ' 06:00:00'  AS DATETIME)
set @hoje = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) + ' 06:00:00' AS DATETIME)
SELECT
  a1.Operator, a1.Time as clockIN, (SELECT top 1 a2.Time FROM dg01.dbo.wgclogfilepos a2
   where a1.Operator = a2.Operator 
      and a2.Event = 13 
      and a1.Time >= @ontem 
      and a1.Time <= @hoje 
      and a2.Time > a1.Time 
   order by a2.Time) AS clockout
FROM dg01.dbo.wgclogfilepos a1 
WHERE Event = 12 
   and a1.Time >= @ontem 
   and a1.Time <= @hoje
ORDER BY a1.Time
```

Now I need to get in each hour the number of employees that are working.

The query results in this table:

```
Operator    clockIN                 clockOUT
DG01E0020   2018-01-27 09:36:46.000 2018-01-27 15:25:53.000
DG01E0027   2018-01-27 10:54:53.000 2018-01-27 19:39:13.000
DG01E0025   2018-01-27 11:48:44.000 2018-01-27 15:32:02.000
DG01E0013   2018-01-27 12:02:56.000 2018-01-27 17:50:41.000
DG01E0032   2018-01-27 12:04:01.000 2018-01-27 16:27:09.000
DG01E0024   2018-01-27 12:04:33.000 2018-01-27 15:21:21.000
DG01E0015   2018-01-27 12:05:49.000 2018-01-27 15:57:39.000
DG01E0012   2018-01-27 12:16:58.000 2018-01-28 00:34:36.000
DG01E0023   2018-01-27 13:04:49.000 2018-01-27 17:05:37.000
DG01E0020   2018-01-27 16:47:20.000 2018-01-27 22:19:13.000
DG01E0032   2018-01-27 18:30:15.000 2018-01-27 23:11:30.000
DG01E0025   2018-01-27 18:45:24.000 2018-01-28 00:02:26.000
DG01E0015   2018-01-27 18:48:04.000 2018-01-28 00:30:13.000
DG01E0024   2018-01-27 18:52:47.000 2018-01-28 00:02:50.000
DG01E0023   2018-01-27 19:08:48.000 2018-01-28 00:32:21.000
DG01E0013   2018-01-27 19:23:14.000 2018-01-27 23:12:12.000
DG01E0013   2018-01-28 00:02:20.000 2018-01-28 00:02:43.000
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wherever required. Also please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have no idea where to start,  I'm a newbie.

Comment: Hint : use `GROUP BY`